# How do I set a filename for a json schema in serverless.ts

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

So the typescript template now builds with a serverless.ts instead of YAML, which is cool - but there is a dearth of examples of how the format of the file works - specifically I'm struggling with the equivalent of yaml's:

```
request:
  schema:
    application/json: ${file(src/schema/login_request.json)}
```

what would x be below?

```
request: {
  schema: {
    'application/json': x
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use Typescript's `import`.

```js
import login_request from './src/schema/login_request.json'

// example how to use the value
const request: {
  schema: {
    'application/json': login_request
  }
}
```